# In WordPress, how can I ReWrite a 'page' URL based on query string parameters?

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting, query-string, permalinks

I have the following page which contains a single post and a number of comments.
    http://mysite.com/tips

When a user posts a comment, I add meta-data to it so I can filter comments by using these URLs:
        
http://mysite.com/tips?id=cat&filter_id=1
        
http://mysite.com/tips?id=dog&filter_id=2

I want to use the following url's instead:
        
http://mysite.com/tips/cat
        
http://mysite.com/tips/dog

I worked through this tutorial, which seemed to be what I needed, but when I type in my url, I get a page not found error. http://thereforei.am/2011/10/28/advanced-taxonomy-queries-with-pretty-urls/

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the admin's dashboard using mysite/wp-admin. Then click on the pages option to view all the pages. Click on the desired page name to edit that page. Just below the name of the page you can see the **permalink**. Edit this to change your page's URL.

Comment: I've want to use 2 different permalinks to filter comments, so this isn't possible.